# How to display an arbitrary Unicode character?

Tags: fonts, unicode

I'm looking for a free font containing ideally all Unicode characters. I'm reading some text concerning Unicode and many of the interesting examples shows like a bunch of empty squares.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a nice table of fonts and their unicode support: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_typefaces#List_of_Unicode_fonts

Comment: Many fonts mentioned there can't be downloaded (broken links), the first working was FreeFont.

Answer (score 1):

[Alan Wood](http://www.alanwood.net) has plenty of info, including [extensive font listings with download links](http://www.alanwood.net/unicode/fonts.html)